# TS6307: Typescript, Vue: the compiler is trying to add '.ts' extension to '.vue' files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue2 + Typescript project. After migration to Vue2.7 I've started to get error messages like

> ```
> import Confirm from '@/components/Confirm.vue'
> ```
>
> TS6307: Imported via '@/components/Confirm.vue' from file '/Users/.../src/main.ts'
> File '/Users/.../components/Confirm.vue.ts' is not listed within the file list of project '/Users/.../tsconfig.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.

And I'm getting the same error for each my `.vue` file. But what is interesting - I'm starting get this messages only if some other (real) error is happened. If my code is OK - no import errors like above.

What settings are responsible for adding extension to file?

My `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    "composite": true
  },
  "vueCompilerOptions": {
    "target": 2.7
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    "src/locales/*.json"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

My `shims-vue.d.ts`

```js
declare module '*.vue' {
  import { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent
  export default component
}
```

Typescript - 5.0.2

Comment: Do you have a `declare module "*.vue" { ... }` d.ts in your projext?

Comment: @Dimava yes, added to the question content

Comment: It's specific to your setup, which is unknown, not TS alone.

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm sure it's setup specific. But which part - webpack, eslint, ts? Any other configs can help?